# State pattern implementation in C++ run into segmentation fault

Tags: c++, state, qnx

I'm implementing state patter in C++, generally all works fine and according to needs, but after state is changed multiple times i get segmentation fault, stack allocation is rising continuously until reach maximum value and then crash
hire is code:
Interface:

```
class ControllerT1; // Forward declaration

class IControllerStateT1 {
public:
    virtual ~IControllerStateT1() {}
    virtual void handle(ControllerT1* controller) = 0;
};



class ControllerT1 {
    public:
        ControllerT1(std::vector<int> &input, std::vector<int> &output);
        ~ControllerT1();

        void stop();
        void initialize();
        void run();

        void setState(IControllerStateT1* newState);

    private:
        IControllerStateT1* currentState;
};


#include "ControllerT1.h"
#include "StopT1.h"

ControllerT1::ControllerT1(std::vector<int> &input, std::vector<int> &output) : currentState(new StopT1()) {
//  ControllerInputs = input;
//  ControllerOutputs = output;
}

ControllerT1::~ControllerT1() {
    delete currentState;
}

void ControllerT1::run() {
    currentState->handle(this);
}

void ControllerT1::stop() {
    currentState->handle(this);
}

void ControllerT1::initialize() {
    //std::cout << "Reading Confihuration files" << std::endl;
    currentState->handle(this);
}

void ControllerT1::setState(IControllerStateT1* newState) {
    delete currentState;
    currentState = newState;
    currentState->handle(this);
}
```

example of state:

```
class RunningT1 : public IControllerStateT1 {
public:
    RunningT1();
    void handle(ControllerT1* controller) override;
};

RunningT1::RunningT1() {

}

void RunningT1::handle(ControllerT1* controller) {

    std::cout<<"Bettery api 1 runing"<<std::endl;
try {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(DataMutex);
    for (auto& element: ControllerOutputs) {
        element=element+1;
    }

} catch (const std::exception&  e) {
    std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
}
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));



    controller->setState(new Intermediate());
}
```

I suspect this part of code to create problems

```
void ControllerT1::setState(IControllerStateT1* newState) {
    delete currentState;
    currentState = newState;
    currentState->handle(this);
}
```

but i don't knew how to change it, i was trying to use pointer there like:

```
std::unique_ptr<IControllerStateT1> newState
```

to avoid using new keyword but problem was the same
i will be grateful for any advice
Program is compiled for QNX x86_64

Comment: the code that uses `std::unique_ptr` would be the more interesting case, because using raw owning pointers is definitely the wrong route and is determined to lead to issues

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: you're recursively setting the state, you'll eventually run out of stack space. Add an external loop to call `currentState->handle`

Comment: Generally using smart pointers is a good idea. You wouldn't have to do much for, just assign a new value to and forget about deleting the old value on re-assignment or controller destruction – that's what the smart pointer takes care of. But your current design still imposes messing around with raw pointers. I see two options instead: `void ControllerT1::setState(std::unique_ptr<IControllerStateT1>&& newState) { currentState = std::move(newState); }` with the r-value reference indicating that the pointer being passed to will be changed (cleared), i.e. setState will transfer ownership.

Comment: There's a [GotW](https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) of Herb Sutter to the topic (smart pointers in parameters) – and that one is really great. The other option is letting the the controller itself create the new states, that could look like this: `template <typename NewState> void setState() { currentState = std::make_unique<NewState>(); }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a basic design flaw. In your

```
void ControllerT1::setState(IControllerStateT1* newState) {
    delete currentState;
    currentState = newState;
    currentState->handle(this);
}
```

you are first deleting the `currentState`, then assigning a new one, then invoking the handling. Now invocation of `currentState->handle(this);` can reach `controller->setState(new Intermediate());` inside of your `handle` routine, and that in turn can `delete` the object whose method `handle` still didn't return possibly causing Undefined Behaviour (might be a crash in your case).

It would be better if you deal with references instead of pointers and keep your State objects inside of a State Machine.

Or you can return a new state from `handle` method, explained quite clearly in [this article](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

Another thing, mentioned by Alan in comments, is the possibly infinite recursion, if you always plan to `handle` inside your `setState`. You should instead "post transition", or similar, in the State Machine.

Comment: I learnt something `new` today -pun intended.

Comment: Just as a side ntoe: Deleting an object that has not yet returned from a member function (another side note: that's the appropriate wording for C++; standard doesn't even know about *'methods'*) actually is unproblematic ***if*** this object is not accessed any more within its own function (i.e. the very last access has already occurred). It is, for instance, possible for objects to delete themselves as very last action within their life time.

Comment: Or you can return a new state from handle method, explained quite clearly in this article. <- this seams to do the job, stack is not rising any more Thanks